# Vuetify, if query parameter exists, show element?

Tags: vue.js

When the form is submitted i want the second `v-card` to display.  I want second `v-card` to only display if query parameter `term` exists..

```
  <v-card class="logo py-4 d-flex justify-center">
   <form>
     <input type="search" name="term" id="term" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" value="Go">
     </form>
  </v-card>
  <v-card v-if="this.$route.query.term != ''">
   Test
  </v-card>
```

When i try this, the second `v-card` always displays regardless of query parameter.

How do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, I did not see any issue in that. Perhaps you could cross-check the `this.$route.query.term` value? Anyhow, I just created a working demo for you.

Demo **:**

```js
const Foo = {
   template: `<div><v-card class="green">
                First Card
              </v-card>
              <v-card class="yellow" v-if="this.$route.query.term !== ''">
                Second Card
              </v-card></div>`
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes : [
    {path: '/foo', component: Foo}
  ] 
});

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  router
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.3.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <router-link :to="{path:'/foo',query:{term:'abc'}}">Show cards</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Right now this demo is showing both the cards as `term` query param value is not empty but you can play around with this code by changing the `term` query param value.